# unsorted Array to Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree

So I am sure this is super easy and I am just missing it but I need to make an unsorted array to BST. I have an array int [] data = { 50, 30, 60, 10, 80, 55, 40 };  and I need to convert it to an unbalanced BST with the first number as the root no matter what I change it to and the other numbers follow the left and right rules. I have this code which works for this array but not if i changed the number to something not in the middle.

```
 public Node arraytoBinary(int [] array, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end){
        return null;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Node node = new Node(array[mid]);
   node.left = arraytoBinary(array, start, mid - 1);
   node.right = arraytoBinary(array, mid + 1, end);

    return node;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a balanced BST? If so this approach requires that the array is sorted. If not, why not iterate through the array and add sequentially to the tree?

Comment: @kingkupps It doesn't have to be a sorted array if you're *inserting* the array elements into a bst, but an array must be sorted to *perform* a binary search on the array. In fact, if it's ordered, and you insert them in order, the bst will devolve to a list. A balanced array also *does not* require sorted arrays; the balancing handles the issue I've mentioned above.

Comment: "I have this code which works for this array but not if i changed the number to something not in the middle." Can you clarify this with an example please?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Right but for this code as is to produce a balanced BST, array must be sorted. Otherwise the produced tree is not guaranteed to be balanced. What do you mean by balanced array?

Comment: @king, according to what they wrote, they're going from array to an *un*-balanced bst and, sorry, I didn't mean to say array, I meant tree. I suppose the part that gets me is, I haven't seen many try to create a balanced tree by ensuring the source array was in a state that facilitated doing so; seems like it defeats the point; nothing stops us from implementing trees with arrays so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ahh understood I misread the question.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils so if I changed the number 50 which is the first number in the Array to 80 instead I would not have a bst that took the first number as the root and created the bst based off of that number. I don’t need to have a balanced bst

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really understand why you try to split the array and it looks like you're making some assumptions about the values and their order. (though to be honest I haven't run your code) You cannot just take for granted the direction (left, right) you'll be going. It depends on the value of the current element and the value held by the current node.

My approach to this would be to define an `insert(Node node, int value)` method and let the `arrayToBinary` simply iterate the array and call `insert`. This will provide you with a clean tree with a minimal interface. Plus, it's based on the definition and insertion logic of a BST so it should be intuitive.

*(pseudo for your pleasure)*
**Insert**

---

```
Node insert(node, value)
    if node is null
        // Create a leaf.
        // It might be the root...
        return new Node(value)

    // It's occupied, see which way to
    // go based on its value

    // right? ...
    if value > node.value
        node.right = insert(node.right, value)

    // or left?
    else if value < node.value
        node.left = insert(node.left, value)

    // Code is not handling dups.
    return node
```

---

**Conversion**

---

```
Node arrayToBinary(array, root)
    for e in array
        root = insert(root, e)
    return root
```

---

This will keep the first element as the root and will insert the rest of the array as expected.

Comment: would this be what you mean?

Comment: private Node insertNode(Node currentParent, Node newNode) {

    if (currentParent == null) {
        return newNode;
    } else if (newNode.value > currentParent.value) {
        currentParent.right = insertNode(currentParent.right, newNode);
    } else if (newNode.value < currentParent.value) {
        currentParent.left = insertNode(currentParent.left, newNode);
    }

                          return currentParent; }'

Comment: @Alexisdiaz, it looks right but is difficult to read like that. Did you give it a go?

Comment: i just need to build the second one you mention yes Ive tried to made it read like code but it wont indent for me for some reason

Comment: For the arraytoBinary what is e supposed to be ?

Comment: @Alexisdiaz, you won't be able to do that in the comment. The e is just the current element in your array. In java, you'd either use an inhanced for loop (`for(int e : array)` or index into it with a traditional for loop (`array[i]` where `i >=0` and `< array.length`). You should be able to slap that together and run both and see that it works. I can add swap it out for runnable python code a bit later.

Comment: **Node arraytoBinary(int [] array, Node root){
    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++){
        root = insertNode(root, i);}
    return root;

}**

Comment: It does not work and gived me 123456789 as my numbers but I am almost positive I am missing something simple

Comment: Yeah, it's not `i` you're inserting, it's `array[i]`. @Alexisdiaz If you  debug that you'll see how your tree is just a list always going right.\